# Java | bitwise operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, lwjgl

I've been using LWJGL for some graphics work. I am unsure how excatly the bitwise operator works. I want to mimic the OpenGL bit flags and check it with an if statement using the `|` bitwise operator.

I would like to reproduce this behavior`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

How can I use an if statement to check if `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` is used and another to check if `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ((myFlags & GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) == GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    // flag is set, act accordingly
```

Note the parens: necessary since [bitwise `&` has a lower precedence than `==`](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

---

Now, why this works... Let us take an hypothetical example:

```
public static final int TEST = 0x4;
// TEST:    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100

value = 35;
// value:   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0011

final boolean b1 = (value & TEST) == TEST; // FALSE

value = 70;
// value:   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0110

final boolean b1 = (value & TEST) == TEST; // TRUE
```

---

Note that in Java, such practices are generally seldomly used; you would generally prefer using an `Enum` instead; however, curiously there doesn't seem to be a "Do It The Java Way(tm)" API for OpenGL... All existing APIs seem to fall short of what is commonly used or, if they don't use it on purpose, do not document it :/

Comment: That's totally correct, but one may prefer a shorter version: `if ((flags & mask) != 0)`, since the mask usually has a single bit set to `1`.

Comment: @cdshines yeah, this is another solution... But explaining all bitops in a 1mn written answer, well... It's not easy ;)

Comment: I don't need all of them. I only needed what you asked. Thank you. If you could upvote my post, that would be good.

Comment: @Zyneak I agree that the flurry of downvotes is not granted here... Upvoted, for what it's worth...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to use the == relational operator seperated with parenthesis instead of the | (OR) logical operator